# automatically create metadata properties in the search application

Tags: search, powershell, search-express

I want to create a number of metadata properties in the search application in sharepoint 2010. I don't want to do this myself. I know it is possible to create a powershell script to create the metadata properties. Is this the right way to create the metadata properties or is there a better way to create the metadata properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a Powershell script is the simplest way, yes. That's what we do.